# Removing one edge from a directed graph G

Tags: machine-learning, bayesian, naivebayes, bayesian-networks, probability-distribution

What will happen if we remove one edge (new graph G') from a directed graph G? For example, does the probability distribution P that factorizes G also factorize G′? and what will happen if G and G′ were undirected graphs?

Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Think of minimal I-map. Minimal I-map is part of the definition of Bayesian Network. That will lead you in the right direction.